# System.IO.FileNotFoundException when running Bridge.LoadAndRegisterAssemblyFrom(File arg0) with Jni4net

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, jni4net

I am trying to make a Jni4net program to act as a bridge between a Java database and a C# application. After doing a few of the samples coming with Jni4net I tried following [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tI0tFUjeffA). After following it thoroughly at the point where his program runs, mine get the error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException

I tried different things with the code for a few hours but without progress. Here is the code, I don't think there is anything wrong with my methods and the file `TestOne.j4n.dll` is indeed under the location `FourthTest/TestOne.j4n.dll`. It's the method `Bridge.LoadAndRegisterAssemblyFrom` that's giving me the error.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import net.sf.jni4net.Bridge;

public class WriteHejsan {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        try{
            Bridge.setVerbose(true);
            Bridge.init();
            Bridge.setDebug(true);
        //  File proxyAssemblyFile = new File("TestOne.j4n.dll");
        //  Bridge.LoadAndRegisterAssemblyFrom(proxyAssemblyFile);
        //  Bridge.LoadAndRegisterAssemblyFrom(new java.io.File("C:/Users/Nikolai/JNIworkspace/FourthTest/TestOne.j4n.dll"));

            Bridge.LoadAndRegisterAssemblyFrom(new java.io.File("TestOne.j4n.dll"));
        //  testone.TestClass.Name();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

The complete error message I get is (some parts in swedish)

```
loading core from C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/jni4net.n-0.8.8.0/0.8.8.0__134a23405600bab4/jni4net.n-0.8.8.0.dll
loading jni4net.n-0.8.8.0, Version=0.8.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=134a23405600bab4 from C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\jni4net.n-0.8.8.0\0.8.8.0__134a23405600bab4\jni4net.n-0.8.8.0.dll
loaded jni4net.n-0.8.8.0, Version=0.8.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=134a23405600bab4 from C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\jni4net.n-0.8.8.0\0.8.8.0__134a23405600bab4\jni4net.n-0.8.8.0.dll
Initialized jni4net core
core loaded from C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/jni4net.n-0.8.8.0/0.8.8.0__134a23405600bab4/jni4net.n-0.8.8.0.dll
clr.version         :v4.0.30319
clr.arch            :64bit
java.home           :C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
java.version        :1.7.0_67
sun.arch.data.model :64
loading TestOne.j4n, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null from C:\Users\Nikolai\JNIworkspace\FourthTest\TestOne.j4n.dll
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Det går inte att läsa in filen eller sammansättningen TestOne, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null eller ett av dess beroenden. Det går inte att hitta filen.
Filnamn: TestOne, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
vid System.Reflection.CustomAttribute._CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule pModule, IRuntimeMethodInfo pCtor, Byte** ppBlob, Byte* pEndBlob, Int32* pcNamedArgs)
vid System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule module, IRuntimeMethodInfo ctor, IntPtr& blob, IntPtr blobEnd, Int32& namedArgs)
vid System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
vid System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
vid net.sf.jni4net.utils.Registry.GetClrWrapperAttribute(Type type)
vid net.sf.jni4net.utils.Registry.RegisterWrapper(Type wrapperType, RegistryRecord& record)
vid net.sf.jni4net.utils.Registry.RegisterType(Type type, Boolean bindJVM, JNIEnv env)
vid net.sf.jni4net.utils.Registry.RegisterAssembly(Assembly assembly, Boolean bindJVM)
vid net.sf.jni4net.Bridge.RegisterAssembly(Assembly assembly)
vid net.sf.jni4net.Bridge.LoadAndRegisterAssemblyFrom(File assemblyFile)
vid net.sf.jni4net.__Bridge.LoadAndRegisterAssemblyFrom3(IntPtr __envp, JniLocalHandle __class, JniLocalHandle assemblyFile)

VARN: Loggningen av sammansättningsbindningen är inaktiverad.
Du kan aktivera felloggning för sammansättningsbindningar genom att ange registervärdet [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) till 1.
Obs! Prestanda kan försämras något med felloggning för sammansättningsbindningar.
Du kan inaktivera funktionen genom att ta bort registervärdet [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

at net.sf.jni4net.Bridge.LoadAndRegisterAssemblyFrom(Native Method)
at WriteHejsan.main(WriteHejsan.java:17)
```

Comment: Try giving forward slash infront of your file name i.e. /TestOne.jn4.dll. Also, i see you have commented the above complete path. Is that commented line working good ?

Comment: "/TestOne.jn4.dll" gave the same error, no they're giving the same System.IO.FileNotFoundException error

Comment: Go to the file "TestOne.jn4.dll" and copy its path by right clicking the properties. Paste that path and execute. Also, check permissions on the file.

Comment: The path in properties is: C:\Users\Nikolai\JNIworkspace\FourthTest\TestOne.j4n.dll
The permission of TestOne.jn4.dll ? if so, where can I check it?

Comment: You can check the file permission when you right click the file and go to properties.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you mean but under properties it says under type: File(Shared Library) and under Attributes it's Archive

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue, I had to move my c# program TestOne.dll to be in the same folder as the TestOne.j4n.dll I created with build.cmd

Answer (score 0):

Place the `.dll` file in the project directory of the `WriteHejsan`  class